# Opencv python to java code conversion

Tags: java, android, python, opencv

I have some code that I want to convert from python to java to use inside my Android application.

The python code is:

```
npaROIResized = imgROI.reshape((1, 600))
```

where `imgROIResized` is a numpy.ndarray that represents a contour I found from an image.

The java code I am trying now is:

```
// points is MatOfPoint that I extracted from a contour
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);  

// matrixImage is the Mat input image
Mat imgROI = matrixImage.submat(rect);

imgROI.reshape(1, 600);
```

but I am getting the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, 
thus its number of rows can not be changed) in 
cv::Mat cv::Mat::reshape(int, int) const, file
```

Comment: Just to be sure: which line gives that error?

Comment: The last line: imgROI.reshape(1, 600);

Comment: matrixImage.submat(rect).clone();